# Searching if trie set is contained in a word

Tags: ruby, algorithm, search, text, trie

Say I have 2 sets:

```
Set A: ['hi', 'there', 'hire', 'hih', 'hih543']

Set B: ['hihow', 'himan, 'fsdko45']
```

Now, these sets in reality each contain close to million elements each.

What I need to do in a nutshell, is filter the set B, in this way

1) For each element of set B, find all elements in set A that are a prefix for it.

So in the above example, when I check set A against `hihow`, I get 2 results: `hi` and `hih`.

2) Say I have `max_offset = 3`. For each of the results I got in set `A`, I should add `[0,1,2,3]` to set A elements length, and if ANY of the results are equal to set B element length then return true.

In this example, let's say we start with `hih`, so I add '1' to it, I add '2' to it, and I get a match, `hih.size + 2 == hihow.size`. The whole operation returns true.

Now, how can I do this in a way where I wouldn't wait for hours for this operation to complete? One approach I figured I could use is to make the 1 set a tries. Say we make set B a tries to allow for a fast look-up.

So now, I iterate over set A elements, and check: For which elements of set B is this element a prefix? So for `'hi'`, I'd get `['hihow', 'himan']`. Now I add `[0,1,2,3]` to `hi.size` and if the result matches the size of any 1 element in the array, that element is a match.

Another approach would be to make set A a tries, and iterate over set B, taking away 0-3 characters at the end of it. So say I take `hihow`, I produce `['hihow', 'hiho', 'hih']` and check all three if any match against set A tries. Yep, there's a match, so this returns true.

I'm afraid I'm missing something in this approach in terms of correctness, so I posted it here. Also, if anyone has a simpler/better way to do this, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: If you already have working code, but you just want to speed it up, you could also ask on [codereview.se]

Answer (score 1):

With this [gem](https://github.com/luikore/triez), it appears to be easier to find words beginning with a prefix than finding prefixes included in a word.

Trie is done from set B. For each match, this code checks if the suffix has  at most 3 characters :

```
# gem install triez
require 'triez'

prefixes = ['hi', 'there', 'hire', 'hih', 'hih543']
words =  ['hihow', 'himan', 'fsdko45']

word_trie = Triez.new
words.each do |word|
  word_trie[word] = 1
end

prefixes.each do |prefix|
  suffixes = word_trie.search_with_prefix(prefix).select{|suffix, id| suffix.size <=3 }
  suffixes.each do |suffix, id|
    word = prefix + '|' + suffix
    puts word
  end
end

# =>
# hi|man
# hi|how
# hih|ow
```